# Colorbox not correct height and width first time HTML is loaded

Tags: colorbox, scrollbars

When I pull in HTML to a colorbox window, there are scrollbars in the box. When I close and reload the colorbox again, it displays fine without the scrollbars. I have tried specifying the width of the containing DIV holding the html that I'm pulling in, but that doesn't seem to help.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any images in the HTML you're pulling in? You'll need to specify the width and height of these otherwise when they're loaded colorbox will think they have a height of 0 and make the box be the appropriate size, the images will then load in and be bigger than 0 causing scrollbars to appear.

It doesn't happen the second time as the browser has cached the height and width of the image.

Hope that helps.